# How to deal with .gcda and .gcno files in different directory by lcov & code coverage compare

Tags: ios, code-coverage, gcov, lcov

I can generate .info files by lcov with .gcda files and .gcno files in the same directory, BUT how can I generate code coverage with .gcda files and .gcno files in defferent location?

For example,

/Users/swd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test1aaeyiowcssrymfbwtudrqqakuvr/Build/Intermediates/test1.build/Cov/test1.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.gcno

/Volumes/Data/test1/test1/AppDelegate.gcda

I tried --add-tracefile but failed, and output 'lcov: ERROR: no valid records found in trace file'

My second question is whether lcov have some command to compare my old version coverage html to my new one, so that I can find the difference.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well few things needs to be cleared first to avoid confusion for other people.

`.gcno` and `.gcda` are never generated on different location for a single object file. (At least that's what I know from my experience)
When a source file is compiled either by using an automated builder or by manual commands, it generates `.gcno` files and `.o` files at the same location. And afterwards when you perform any kind of execution the object files trigger coverage generation functions and generate `.gcda` files at the same location as '.gcno' and object files.
And if they are generated for different `.gcno` files then they can not be used together anyway.

Comment: If the environment variable `GCOV_PREFIX`is set to some path gcov adds that path in front of the absolute paths in the `.o` file and generates the `.gcda` file there.

Comment: And this is typically done to be able to run the program in many parallel processes, like with many tests run with "make -j test"

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if the environment variable `GCOV_PREFIX` is set. See [here](http://bobah.net/book/export/html/2)
The suggested solution is to release the `.gcno` files to `$GCOV_PREFIX` by doing something like

```
rsync -acv --filter='+ */' --filter='+ *.gcno' --filter='- *' <directory-containing-object-files> $GCOV_PREFIX
```

Comment: This is very expensive if you are running many tests in different directories with GCOV_PREFIX set to generate separate sets. Then you need to copy the `.gcno` files many times. `rsync` helps a bit since it does not copy files unnecessarily. But is there actually no better method? Like a switch or environment variable?