# Generate native code coverage report from 2 sets of .gcda files and one set of .gcno files

Tags: c++, code-coverage, lcov

I'm using lcov to generate code coverage report for native part of the product.
Using the command `lcov --capture --directory <path_to_obj> --output-file coverage.info` (path_to_obj - path to dir with all .gcno and .gcda files are) it's not a problem to generate report.

But, if I have several sets of (directories with) .gcda files and one set (a directory with) .gcno files.
**Is it possible to generate the report as the files are?** (not copying .gcno files to each folder with .gcda files)
I know that I can copy .gcno files to each folder with .gcda files, generate .info files and then merge them, but I want to avoid that.

From the man lcov, I can see that --directory parameter stands for "Use .da (as I understood .gcda files counts here) files in directory instead of kernel." Also, "Note that you may specify this option more than once."
But I didn't find similar parameters for specifying .gcno files location, **is there such at all or they must(!) lay together?**

I saw the question [How to deal with .gcda and .gcno files in different directory by lcov & code coverage compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27940017/how-to-deal-with-gcda-and-gcno-files-in-different-directory-by-lcov-code-cov) and saw a comment that .gcno and .gcda files should be generated at the same location, but in my case, they are not generated in one location (it's a correct behavior).